# Files disappearing on flash drive in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I just don't get it, I haven't modified any files. And When I moved my work on to my USB it disappeared after I plugged it back it. I would really appreciate it if their was any way of fixing this because This is a really big school project. Thank you for trying.

Comment: silly question but do the files have a leading dot in the filename ? like `.somefile` ?  Also, have you tried enabling hidden files in file manager or look through the folder with `ls -a` command ?

Comment: yes I see the extension the extension is .docx and I do have the Hidden files  showing

Comment: No, what I mean is hidden files all have leading dot in the name, like `.hiddenfile.dox` , the . before hidden would make the file hidden. How did you move those files to USB by the way?

Comment: No, the file didn't have that, and I saved the file straight to the USB from LibreOffice Writer with a .docx

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to tell you, my friend.   Did you have a copy of the file saved somewhere else ?  Try also open Recent Documents in Libre Office Writer with the USB plugged in.

Comment: The recent document with the USB plugged in worked! Thank you

Comment: OK, I guess I'll post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files have been actually saved to USB, then you may find them with opening Recent Documents in LibreOffice Writer while USB is plugged in, and it will search the path where that document may have been saved and recover it.